# Problema con acomodar Divs

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy haciendo una vista médica, solo que tengo un problema con el CSS o con el código.
Necesito que la caja que dice diagnóstico aparezca debajo de visitas anteriores.
Intenté hacerlo pero sigue apareciendo abajo, de hecho a lado derecho de estos dos va otro div que tiene la información de "Antecedentes no patológicos"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Expedientes digitales</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.vertical-tabs.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1 class="text-center">Juan<br> <small>Pérez Sánchez</small></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="min-height:600px;">
      <div  class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#general_info" data-toggle="tab">Información general</a></li>
            <li><a href="#history" data-toggle="tab">Historial clínico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#new_element" data-toggle="tab">Nuevo diagnóstico</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="general_info"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="history">
              <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#antescedentes_generales">Antescedentes generales</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_agudeza">Agudeza visual</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_quera">Queratometría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_reti">Retinoscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_bio">Biomicroscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_tono">Tonometría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_ofta">Oftalmoscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_paqui">Paquimetría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_topo">Topografía</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_campi">Campimetría</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="antescedentes_generales" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                      <div class="column-left">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                          <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Visitas anteriores</a>
                              </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                              <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                  <li><a>Consulta 1</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 2</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 3</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 4</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 5</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 6</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 7</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 8</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 9</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 10</a><li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    < <div class="column-left text-center">
                        <label>Diagnóstico<br><small>Por Lic. Optometría José Manuel Cruz Ceballos</small></label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Información del diagnóstico" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Phasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                        <textarea placeholder="Plan" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Phasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                        <textarea placeholder="Notas y observaciones" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Phasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                      </div>
                      <div class="div2">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                          <h2 class="text-center">Antescedentes personales no patológicos</h2>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tabaquismo</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="smoking" name="smoking">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="per_day_div_smoking">
                            <label>Cigarrillos por día</label>
                            <input id="per_day_input_smoking" type="number" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="duration_div_smoking">
                            <label>Duración en minutos</label>
                            <input type="number" id="duration_input_smoking" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>

                          <br><br>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Alcoholismo</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="alcohol" name="alcohol">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>


                          <div class="form-group" id="class_div_alcohol">
                            <label>Clase de bebida</label>
                            <input type="text" id="class_input_alcohol" class="form-control alinear sm-input" placeholder="Indica que clase de bebida">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="quantity_div_alcohol">
                            <label>Cantidad</label>
                            <input type="number" id="quantity_input_alcohol" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>


                          <br><br>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Toxicomonios</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="toxic" name="toxic">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="class_div_toxic">
                            <label>Tipo</label>
                            <input type="text" id="class_input_toxic" class="form-control alinear gd-input" placeholder="Tipo de toxicomonio">
                          </div>

                          <h2 class="text-center">Antescedentes personales patológicos</h2>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="1"> Enfermedades cardiovasculares<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="2"> Diabetes Menitus<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="3"> Hipertensión arterial<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="4"> Enfermedades neurológicas<br>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="5"> Cáncer o tumor<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="6"> Enfermedades renales<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="7"> Enfermedades hepáticas<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="8"> Enfermedades de la tiroides<br>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="9"> Cirugía visual previa<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="10"> Otras enfermedades <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Describir</a>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                  <h4 class="modal-title">Describe la enfermedad</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <input type="text" id="modal_disease" class="form-control alinear gd-input" placeholder="Indica la enfermedad">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Listo</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab_agudeza" class="tab-pane fade">
                  </div>

                  <div id="tab_quera" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Queratometría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_reti" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Retinoscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_bio" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Biomicroscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_tono" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Tonometría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_ofta" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Oftalmoscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_paqui" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Paquimetría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_topo" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Topografía</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_campi" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Campimetría</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="new_element"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el CSS

```
.alinear
{
  width: 100px;
}

.div1
{
  background: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}


.div2
{
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.merk
{
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#ultima_consulta
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}

.diagnostico
{
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 225px;
  max-height: 110px;
  min-width: 225px;
  min-height: 110px;
}

.column-left {
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    cursor:pointer;
}




.sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 10em;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.sub-menu li {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: .25em 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Debería aparecer así pero el div de Diagnóstico debajo de visitas anteriores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar mas del CSS que tienes para los demás divs?

Comment: Edito mejor todo y pongo el código completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución rápida es incluir el contenedor de "Diagnóstico" en el que tiene la clase `column-left` que es el que contiene las visitas anteriores. Al contenedor de "Diagnóstico" le quitamos la clase `column-left` y realicé una pequeña modificación en el ancho de la columan de la derecha, la de los antecedentes.

Depende como vayas a manejar las vistas para teléfonos celulares, tablets, etc. se podrían mejorar los estilos aplicados.

```css
.alinear {
  width: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: calc(80% - 20px);
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.merk {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#ultima_consulta {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}

.diagnostico {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 225px;
  max-height: 110px;
  min-width: 225px;
  min-height: 110px;
}

.column-left {
    top: 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 10em;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.sub-menu li {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: .25em 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.sub-menu li:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Expedientes digitales</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.vertical-tabs.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1 class="text-center">Juan<br> <small>Pérez Sánchez</small></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="min-height:600px;">
      <div  class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#general_info" data-toggle="tab">Información general</a></li>
            <li><a href="#history" data-toggle="tab">Historial clínico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#new_element" data-toggle="tab">Nuevo diagnóstico</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="general_info"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="history">
              <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#antescedentes_generales">Antescedentes generales</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_agudeza">Agudeza visual</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_quera">Queratometría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_reti">Retinoscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_bio">Biomicroscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_tono">Tonometría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_ofta">Oftalmoscopia</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_paqui">Paquimetría</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_topo">Topografía</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_campi">Campimetría</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="antescedentes_generales" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                      <div class="column-left">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                          <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Visitas anteriores</a>
                              </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                              <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                  <li><a>Consulta 1</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 2</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 3</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 4</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 5</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 6</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 7</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 8</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 9</a><li>
                                  <li><a>Consulta 10</a><li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                        <label>Diagnóstico<br><small>Por Lic. Optometría José Manuel Cruz Ceballos</small></label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Información del diagnóstico" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Pasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                        <textarea placeholder="Plan" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Phasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                        <textarea placeholder="Notas y observaciones" class="diagnostico">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam lacinia magna quis pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur enim arcu, ultrices at vehicula sit amet, egestas ut lectus. Sed laoreet ultricies mauris. Proin iaculis, augue non vehicula lacinia, lacus ipsum cursus augue, id dictum turpis justo quis urna. Phasellus a suscipit neque, non convallis lectus. Phasellus efficitur, magna sit amet ullamcorper ultricies, lectus elit imperdiet leo, in molestie neque enim in velit. Sed sagittis elit dapibus eros laoreet, id pellentesque erat fermentum. Proin consequat dictum elit et posuere. Proin feugiat libero quis magna tincidunt suscipit. Donec pretium purus vel hendrerit consectetur. Fusce eu ligula non eros congue aliquam. Sed sagittis tempor elit nec ultrices. Aliquam bibendum pharetra aliquam.
                          Cras efficitur fermentum nulla, non vehicula orci convallis at. Morbi ut urna sed mi accumsan accumsan a sed lorem. Aliquam mattis aliquet urna. Mauris sed justo id diam sollicitudin aliquet. Donec eget nunc erat. Integer non maximus tellus. Vestibulum risus purus, facilisis sit amet dapibus vitae, posuere ut augue. In pulvinar lobortis mattis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras maximus leo gravida nisi consequat, nec efficitur metus ornare. Etiam varius vitae mi bibendum faucibus. Sed porta justo eros, ac blandit mauris lobortis quis. Suspendisse feugiat augue vitae sem facilisis placerat. Quisque eleifend maximus eros varius ultricies. Praesent id dapibus ligula. Sed ac imperdiet sem.
                        </textarea>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="div2">
                        <form class="form-inline">
                          <h2 class="text-center">Antescedentes personales no patológicos</h2>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Tabaquismo</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="smoking" name="smoking">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="per_day_div_smoking">
                            <label>Cigarrillos por día</label>
                            <input id="per_day_input_smoking" type="number" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="duration_div_smoking">
                            <label>Duración en minutos</label>
                            <input type="number" id="duration_input_smoking" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>

                          <br><br>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Alcoholismo</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="alcohol" name="alcohol">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>


                          <div class="form-group" id="class_div_alcohol">
                            <label>Clase de bebida</label>
                            <input type="text" id="class_input_alcohol" class="form-control alinear sm-input" placeholder="Indica que clase de bebida">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="quantity_div_alcohol">
                            <label>Cantidad</label>
                            <input type="number" id="quantity_input_alcohol" class="form-control alinear" min="1" max="99">
                          </div>


                          <br><br>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Toxicomonios</label>
                            <select class="form-control alinear" id="toxic" name="toxic">
                              <option disabled selected value="0">Elige</option>
                              <option value="1">No</option>
                              <option value="2">Si</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group" id="class_div_toxic">
                            <label>Tipo</label>
                            <input type="text" id="class_input_toxic" class="form-control alinear gd-input" placeholder="Tipo de toxicomonio">
                          </div>

                          <h2 class="text-center">Antescedentes personales patológicos</h2>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="1"> Enfermedades cardiovasculares<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="2"> Diabetes Menitus<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="3"> Hipertensión arterial<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="4"> Enfermedades neurológicas<br>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="5"> Cáncer o tumor<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="6"> Enfermedades renales<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="7"> Enfermedades hepáticas<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="8"> Enfermedades de la tiroides<br>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="9"> Cirugía visual previa<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="app" value="10"> Otras enfermedades <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Describir</a>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                  <h4 class="modal-title">Describe la enfermedad</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  <input type="text" id="modal_disease" class="form-control alinear gd-input" placeholder="Indica la enfermedad">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Listo</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab_agudeza" class="tab-pane fade">
                  </div>

                  <div id="tab_quera" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Queratometría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_reti" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Retinoscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_bio" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Biomicroscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_tono" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Tonometría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_ofta" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Oftalmoscopia</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_paqui" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Paquimetría</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_topo" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Topografía</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tab_campi" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Aquí es la información de Campimetría</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="new_element"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="validation.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitaba. Gracias Shaz.